# Android Studio auto change punctuation

Tags: android-studio

When I input `。` (Chinese) in Android Studio, it automatically changes to `.`(English). Why does this happen, I have changed my input source, but this continues to happen.

I have seen my colleague's Android Studio. His is normal.

I had Googled for it, but no answer, my English is poor.

May be I had configured something?

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: What's the encoding of your file?

Comment: My file encoding is utf-8

Comment: 1. Check the current font File/Settings/Colors & Fonts/Font and compare it with your colleagues